# semantic-release keeps committing dist and docs to repo despite .gitignore

Tags: node.js, git, github-actions, semantic-release

Im using `semantic-release` to build and publish an NPM package. The build process creates a `dist\` and `docs\` directory which is properly set to be ignored in the `.gitignore`. Once the build stage is done, I then use the `upload-artifact` github action to pass them to the `release` stage. On the `release` stage I just retrieve the artifact and run `npx semantic-release` to publish the package.

This all works great, the package is correctly published and it has all the files I expect. However, `semantic-release` commits the `dist\` and `docs\` into the repo despite them being in the `.gitignore`. Im sure its just a configuration step Im missing. Any thoughts?

`semantic-release` config (in `package.json`):

```
"release": {
    "branches": [
        {
            "name": "main"
        },
        {
            "name": "develop",
            "channel": "beta",
            "prerelease": "beta"
        }
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
        [
            "@semantic-release/changelog",
            {
                "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
            }
        ],
        "@semantic-release/npm",
        "@semantic-release/github",
        [
            "@semantic-release/git",
            {
                "assets": [
                    "CHANGELOG.md",
                    "dist/**",
                    "docs/**"
                ],
                "message": "chore(release): set `package.json` to ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
            }
        ]
    ]
},
```

Heres a screenshot of the `semantic-release-bot` committing `dist\` and `docs\` back to the repo (along with changelog, which is expected)

[image: commit]

Relevant part of `.gitignore`

```
## docs
/docs/

# build
/_site/
/dist/
/out-tsc/
```

Comment: 1) Can we see your .gitignore? 2) The path separator is `/` not ```\```. Use `dist/`. 3) .gitignore only prevents new files from being tracked, are there already files committed in dist and docs? 4) Test your .gitignore by creating some files and seeing if they're ignored

Comment: @Schwern Added relevant part of gitignore to question at the end. It does work for other folders (like the code coverage folder for example)

Comment: @Schwern's third point is the big one, though: if something had already been added from `dist` and `docs` then .gitignore will not retroactively forget that.

Comment: @JimRedmond Each time its happened I purge it again (and check in said purge), still comes back

Comment: @Hershizer33 What do you mean by "purge"? `git rm -r docs dist` and then commit? And if you save a file like `docs/test` then it does not show up in `git status`?

Comment: @Schwern Correct. I just created a new file `docs/test.txt` and `git status` correctly says noting to report

Comment: Hello, I notice you are using "prerelease": "beta" on your branches configuration, I think that prerelease is supposed to be a boolean, for example: "prerelease": true according to https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/v23.0.0-beta.1/docs/recipes/release-workflow/pre-releases.md#publishing-pre-releases

Answer (score 0):

Update ur file (i mean its .releaserc.js) to

```
"release": {
    "branches": [
        {
            "name": "main"
        },
        {
            "name": "develop",
            "channel": "beta",
            "prerelease": "beta"
        }
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer",
        "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator",
        [
            "@semantic-release/changelog",
            {
                "changelogFile": "CHANGELOG.md"
            }
        ],
        "@semantic-release/npm",
        "@semantic-release/github",
        [
            "@semantic-release/git",
            {
                assets: ['CHANGELOG.md', 'package.json', 'package-lock.json'],
                "message": "chore(release): set `package.json` to ${nextRelease.version} [skip ci]\n\n${nextRelease.notes}"
            }
        ]
    ]
},
```

(update "@semantic-release/git".assets)
when u put `"dist/**", "docs/**"` to "@semantic-release/git".assets semantic release add them to commit

u can see example of deploy semantic release with typescript here

https://github.com/JS-AK/example-automatic-deploy-ts-app-to-npm-with-scope